# How does SMF calculate the attachment hash?

Tags: smf

I am struggling with an SMF database collapse. I see files like `57657_91d53e636a4a5cf62f2be632136fb1caba7f6be7` in the attachment directory. What is used as the source for the hash? The `sha1sum` of the file itself doesn't match.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the attachments file name (hash) using the function getAttachmentFileName(). The SMF function library provides the arguments

http://support.simplemachines.org/function_db/index.php?action=view_function;id=238